# Control column width with left alignment in tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, width

I want to make a table with a bigger than default column width for the first column. The text in this column should be left aligned. Here is my code.

```
\begin{tabular}{llll|l}
Address1    &&&& Mobile: 888-000-0000 \\
Address2    &&&& Fax: 888-000-0000 \\
\end{tabular}
```

The first column (Address1, Address2) should have a larger width so that the second column (Mobile, Fax) is close to the right margin of the page. Now I just add in a lot of invisible columns so that there are more spaces between them. I wonder if there is a way to control the width of the first column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to achieve your objective. One of them would be to use a `tabular*` environment instead of a `tabular` environment:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l}
Address1    & Mobile: 888-000-0000 \\
Address2    & Fax: 888-000-0000 \\
\end{tabular*}
```

The somewhat intimidating-looking contruct `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` serves to push the table's columns maximally far apart (while making the entire table still fit into a text block of width `\textwidth`).

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT 21.4.2020 I do *not* recommend using [tabu](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) anymore. It is unsupported and buggy**

You can use the package [tabu](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/tabu). You adjust the width of each column by changing the value 5 and 2.5 inside the brackets. You may also change the alignment from left to right or centred, by changing `l`to `r`(or `c`). Here is your table:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X[5,l]|X[2.5,l]}
Address1    & Mobile: 888-000-0000 \\
Address2    & Fax: 888-000-0000 \\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick-and-dirty solution with `tabularx`:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
...
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|l}
Address1 & Mobile: 888-000-0000 \\
Address2 & Fax: 888-000-0000 \\
\end{tabularx}
```

But bear in mind that it's prettier without the vertical bar.

Comment: Note that doing this with tabularx rather than tabular* makes TeX work 10000000 times harder. It maybe that with today's machine speeds you don't care anymore, but....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : My guess was that OP might be a relative beginner; while I agree that my answer is not, technically, the best possible, I certainly think it's the *least scary* (for a beginner, anyway).

Comment: I get scared every time anyone uses tabularx